# cleveref and customized refname

Tags: cleveref

Is it possible with `cleveref` to customize on the fly the name in the clickable link? If you consider the basic example below, the idea would be to have "Condition (1)" active (as opposed to the current "Equation (1)".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
It is true that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:cos}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
However, Condition~\Cref{eq:cos} should be considered with care.
\end{document}
```

Partial answer [Posted after Mico's answer and including Circumscribe's comment]: this can be achieved manually with the `\hyperref` command:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:cos} 
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
However, \hyperref[eq:cos]{Condition~\ref*{eq:cos}} should be considered with care.
```

Comment: In your partial answer you may want to use `\ref*` instead of `\ref` since you've got a nested hyperlink now.

Comment: @Circumscribe Good point. I am not sure what the difference is?

Comment: The difference is that `\ref*{<label>}` generates a reference that's not a hyperlink. It'll still say, for instance, “equation (1)”, but it won't be highlighted/boxed or clickable.

Comment: Why not just the following?  `However, the condition in \Cref{eq:cos}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mico's answer is of course interesting but it looks like new developments are needed. Instead a manual solution is possible:

```
However, \hyperref[eq:cos]{Condition~\eqref*{eq:cos}} should be considered with care.
```

It is thus possible to define a new command (here for equations) with two arguments (the *term* to be used and the label)

```
\newcommand*{\myrefeq}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{#1~(\ref*{#2})}}
```

We can then use it with the appropriate term, depending on the need: `In \myrefeq{Equation}{eq:label}...` or `In \myrefeq{Condition}{eq:label}...` where the hyperlink is on the full `Equation (1)` or `Condition (1)`.

Comment: This is not an answer for the posted question.

Comment: @hesham Yes I agree but at this point there is not `cleveref` only solution and can still be of interest to readers.

Answer (score 8):

You asked,

> Is it possible with `cleveref` to customize on the fly the name in the clickable link?

Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: Your typographic objective may be achieved using `cleveref`'s aliasing capabilities. For more information, see section 6 of the package's user guide, entitled "Overriding the Cross-Reference Type".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% introduce an alias for 'equation'
\crefalias{condition}{equation}
\crefname{condition}{condition}{conditions}
\Crefname{condition}{Condition}{Conditions}
\creflabelformat{condition}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3} % same as 'equation'

\begin{document}
It is true that
\begin{equation} \label[condition]{eq:cos} % note the optional argument of '\label'
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
However, \Cref{eq:cos} should be considered with care.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting thank you! However I can no longer refer to the proposed equation as "Equation (1)" in the text, right? It will always be "Condition (1)" now? Something like `\Cref[condition]{eq:cos}` (for condition) and `\Cref{eq:cos}` (for equation) would be great, to have both  versions in the text!

Comment: @pluton - If you refer to some object as "Condition (1)" in some places and as "Equation (1)" in some others, you will most assuredly confuse your readers to no end. Don't do it.

Comment: @pluton - What you're asking for is a feature request. Feature requests are off-topic for this site. I suggest you direct it at the author/maintainer of the cleveref package. You may find his contact information on p. 1 of the user guide of the cleveref package. That said, I continue to think it'll confuse your readers needlessly if you use more than one noun to label a given object.

Comment: I did not know it was a feature request. I might contact the author. Yes, I  do not disagree with you but sometimes what's within a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` is fairly obvious (like an inequality), and varying the terminology makes the text nicer. Saying "In Inequality (1)" is thus clear and equivalent to saying "In Equation (1)"...

Comment: In fact, it can be done manually with the `\hyperlink` command:\begin{equation} \label{eq:cos} 
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
However, \hyperlink{eq:cos}{Condition \ref{eq:cos}} should be considered with care